# Can you display a program on a secondary monitor with the console secured under Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, driver, win64

In the video surveillance industry, this is called running a "spot monitor".  My current environment is Windows 7 embedded.  I need to secure the system, ideally by locking the console session, while leaving a program that displays video active on multiple remote secondary displays.  Unfortunately, Windows "blanks" all the secondary display devices when you lock the console.

I have detached displays, created separate non-interactive WindowStations/desktops, new Device Contexts, but no matter what, the displays blank when I lock the console.

```
        bool rval = false;
        IntPtr hWinStaOrig, hWinSta, hDesktop;
        Win32.DEVMODE dm = GetDevMode();
        Win32.DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new Win32.DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        d.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(d);
        if (Win32.EnumDisplayDevices(null, deviceID, ref d, 0))
        {
            if (((d.StateFlags & Win32.DisplayDeviceStateFlags.AttachedToDesktop) != 0) && 
                ((d.StateFlags & Win32.DisplayDeviceStateFlags.PrimaryDevice) == 0))
            {
                if (Win32.EnumDisplaySettingsEx(d.DeviceName, Win32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm, 0) != 0)
                {
                    dm.dmPelsWidth = 0;
                    dm.dmPelsHeight = 0;
                    dm.dmFields = Win32.DmFlags.DM_POSITION | Win32.DmFlags.DM_PELSWIDTH | Win32.DmFlags.DM_PELSHEIGHT;
                    if (Win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                        d.DeviceName,
                        ref dm,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        Win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | Win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_RESET, // | Win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_GLOBAL ,
                        IntPtr.Zero
                        ) == (int)Win32.DISP_CHANGE.SUCCESSFUL)
                    {
                        hWinStaOrig = Win32.GetProcessWindowStation();
                        hWinSta = Win32.CreateWindowStation("MyWinSta", Win32.CWF_CREATE_ONLY,
                            Win32.ACCESS_MASK.WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS | Win32.ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL,
                            0);
                        if (hWinSta != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            if (Win32.SetProcessWindowStation(hWinSta))
                            {
                                    hDesktop = Win32.CreateDesktop("MyDesktop", null, null, Win32.DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, Win32.ACCESS_MASK.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, 0);
                                if (hDesktop != IntPtr.Zero)
                                {
                                    if (AttachDisplayDevice(deviceID))
                                    {
                                        IntPtr hDC = Gdi32.CreateDC(d.DeviceName, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                                        if (hDC != IntPtr.Zero)
                                        {
                                            Win32.RECT r;
                                            r.left = 10;
                                            r.top = 10;
                                            r.right = 400;
                                            r.bottom = 300;

                                            Gdi32.SetTextColor(hDC, 0xffffff);
                                            Gdi32.SetBkColor(hDC, 0x0);

                                            if (Win32.DrawText(hDC, "Hello, Bozo!", -1, ref r, Win32.DT_CENTER | Win32.DT_VCENTER | Win32.DT_SINGLELINE) == 0)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("DrawText failed!");
                                            }

                                            Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue...");
                                            Console.ReadLine();

                                            Gdi32.DeleteDC(hDC);
                                        }
                                        DetachDisplayDevice(deviceID);
                                    }
                                    if (!Win32.CloseDesktop(hDesktop))
                                    {
                                        Error("CloseDesktop");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Error("CreateDesktop");
                                }
                                if (!Win32.SetProcessWindowStation(hWinStaOrig))
                                {
                                    Error("SetProcessWindowStation Failed!");
                                }
                            }
                            rval = Win32.CloseWindowStation(hWinSta);
                        }
                        AttachDisplayDevice(deviceID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return rval;
    }
```

Do I need a completely separate session?  Is that even possible under Windows 7?  Am I running down the wrong path altogether?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to keep one or more displays active while securing a Windows 7 box?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Kiosk mode and just allowing a single app with no access to the shell? You can always have a "get out" method, but for this type of application Kiosk mode looks like it is what you need. [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/08/03/building-public-kiosk-stations-with-windows-7-and-windows8-itpro.aspx) may help...

Comment: Yes.  I saw this article too and considered it but so-called "kiosk mode" is not totally secure.  It mostly just hides a bunch of buttons - a knowledgeable user could defeat it.  Did I mention, these are security systems?   That being said, I may have to revisit it if I cannot come up with something better.  Thanks for the reply, Ron.

Comment: Oh, and I suppose it would be good to mention: these systems are typically maintained remotely using MSTSC which automatically locks the session when you disconnect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need to detach the video card from being owned by whichever driver owns it (my guess would be win32k.sys - the kernel part of the Win32 subsystem) and then have a driver you write talk to the graphics driver directly. You'd also need to have a video app that would output the video feed to an interface your driver provided. A lot of work if I'm right. BTW, in the more distant past I've found a lot of locked down Windows systems to be relatively easy to "break" into. However in the last 5 or so years I've found them to resist 10-20 minutes of my efforts.